Is UBUNTU able to use Proton Mail? And what about having Tahoma as a font?
Is UBUNTU able to use Proton Mail?
And what about having Tahoma as a font?

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you downloaded the .deb installation file for the Proton Mail application? If so, are you having trouble installing the software? With regards to the font, the open source alternatives for Tahoma are generally Lucida Sans, Liberation Sans, and DejaVu Sans.

Have you tried anything? or just posted without doing any of your own reading.

Glad to see that there is an App for Proton Mail.

Sorry, but I am new to UBUNTU, and lots to learn.

One question per post, please.

electron-mail is an unofficial Proton Mail desktop app that is available in Ubuntu as a snap package. To install electron-mail in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:
sudo snap install electron-mail

Liberation Sans font is a clear, easy to read font in Ubuntu that I regard as a good open source alternative to the popular Tahoma font because it renders well on other operating systems such as Windows and macOS..
